# image as anchor in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

how to make an image as an anchor in codeigniter? I've tried the following code,

> echo anchor("admin/conf/edit/".$list['id'],img(array('src' => '../img/edit.jpg', 'alt' => "")));

It gives me a grey box like in the Actions column

[image]

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
anchor("admin/conf/edit/".$list['id'], img('src'=>'../img/edit.jpg','border'=>'0');
```

or

```
anchor("admin/conf/edit/".$list['id'], img('src'=>'../img/edit.jpg','style'=>'border:0px');
```

Comment: woops didn't see your comment.
However it is considered good practice to give a little heads-up when you find the answer yourself; other people might have the same problem with you.

Comment: Sorry Iraklis,thanks a lot for the answer...Sorry for the late comments... ^_^

Comment: Also you might want to answer your own question... with what worked for you.  Give back a little. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should first load the html helper class and then

```
$img = array('src' => '../img/edit.jpg','width'=>'25','height' =>"10");

echo anchor($path, img($img));
```

Should be good enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

**This would work:**

```
$path = 'admin/conf/edit/' .$list['id'];
$img = '<img src="../img/edit.jpg" alt="">';?>
echo anchor($path, $img);
```

**And with html helper:**

```
$img = array(
    'src' => '../img/edit.jpg',
    'alt' => ''
);
$path = 'admin/conf/edit/' .$list['id'];
echo anchor($path, img($img));
```